# Javascript delete cookie next day

Tags: javascript, cookies

I was wonder if you can delete a cookie at the beginning of the next day.

Lets say I log in to a website at 1:30pm and use it again throughout the day but at midnight or 1 minute past, in the new day, the cookie is removed.

Many thanks for any help,
C

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes - set an expiry time of midnight:

```
function midnight_cookie(name, value, path)
{
  var now = new Date();
  var expire = new Date();
  expire.setFullYear(now.getFullYear());
  expire.setMonth(now.getMonth());
  expire.setDate(now.getDate()+1);
  expire.setHours(0);
  expire.setMinutes(0);
  document.cookie = name+"="+value+"; expires=" + expire.toString() +"; path=" + path;
}
```

Comment: umm, you have an error in your code. date on line 7 is undefined

Comment: I'm sure a smart guy like you can figure out what it should have been.

Answer (score 0):

Give the cookie an appropriate expiry datetime.

Answer (score 0):

You can let cookies expire on a given date / time. Have a look at the setCookie function here:

http://techpatterns.com/downloads/javascript_cookies.php